# Get the latest price in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

Using e.g. built-in variable `close` in pine script allows me to get the close price of the *current candle* at the position in the chart where the script is executed.
Using `close[1], close[2], ...` I can look into history.

How can I obtain the **latest price of the stock** (looking into the *future*)?
Note: I don't just want to check if the current bar is the latest bar.

Answer (score 0):

close is always the latest stock price
Try plot the close line, on a one-minute chart, and you will see that the line changes its value (last stock price) before the close.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
plot(close)
```

Comment: Your code would re-print chart itself. I want to use the *currrent price* of the stock in my calculations (the latest price of today!) and NOT the latest price when standing at some candle / time point in the history. Standing at this time point in history, I am looking into the future and wan't to get today's latest stock price.

Comment: the latest price of today is close. Could you explain in other words?

Comment: Your code `plot(close)` draws for each candle stick the close price. My desired behavior woud be printing a horizontal line through the whole chart at latest price. Do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

To plot a horizontal line through the whole chart at latest price

1. Use the last value of *close* with [barstate.islast](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_barstate%7Bdot%7Dislast)
2. Plot a line with [line.new](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_line%7Bdot%7Dnew)

Something like that

```
//@version=5
indicator(title = 'test', overlay = true)

var line lastPrice = na
if barstate.islast
    line.delete(lastPrice)
    lastPrice := line.new(
      bar_index[1], close,
      bar_index, close,
      xloc.bar_index,
      extend.both,
      color.new(color.orange, 0),
      line.style_solid,
      1)
```

Answer (score 0):

- To get the future price, as declared by you, you will either need to

  a) fetch an external time machine api (but neither does that exist nor does pine script allow dynamic fetch requests to custom sources)

  b) **or** be a lot more precise on your ask, as, at the realtime bar and the stock market being open, the close price of the day (which is in the future) is not known and therefore can not be printed anywhere.

If you only want to display a price line for the current price extending to the right, with no plots between the candles, the following is what you likely want.

```
//@version=5

indicator("Close", overlay = true)

// Create a simple boolean switch (results into TRUE/FALSE)
// to verify your script only execute on the last bar.
// In pine script, the last bar, is the current bar.
bool isNow  = barstate.islast         

// Add this condition to your plot statement.
// This now checks whether it may plot or not at the bar.
plot(isNow ? close : na,
     title = '',
     color = color.red,
     linewidth = 1,
     style = plot.style_line,
     trackprice = true,
     editable = false,
     display = display.pane)
```