# line.new with automatic pourcentage

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I would like to have a horizontal line that moves according to the current price.

For example, the line should be x% higher than the current price.

X% = the % of the current candle

I have try with line.new but i have a vertical line.
Thanks

Comment: Check [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75364097/get-the-latest-price-in-pine-script/75388673#75388673)

Answer (score 0):

I have create this

```
    //@version=5
indicator('TP SL lines', overlay=true)

per = math.abs((close-close[1]) / close[1])

price_top = math.round(close+(per*close), 5)
price_buttom = math.round(close-(per*close), 5)

var line l1 = na
var line l2 = na
l1 := line.new(bar_index[1], price_top, bar_index, price_top, color=color.red, style=line.style_solid, width=2, extend = extend.right)
l2 := line.new(bar_index[1], price_buttom, bar_index, price_buttom, color=color.red, style=line.style_solid, width=2, extend = extend.right)

line.delete(l1[1])
line.delete(l2[1])

var label top = na
var label buttom = na

if not na(l1)
    top := label.new(bar_index + 3, price_top, text=str.format("{0,number,0.00000}", price_top), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, color=color.white, style=label.style_label_lower_left)

if not na(top[1])
    label.delete(top[1])


if not na(l2)
    buttom := label.new(bar_index + 7, price_buttom, text=str.format("{0,number,0.00000}", price_buttom), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, color=color.white, style=label.style_label_upper_left)

if not na(buttom[1])
    label.delete(buttom[1])
```